# Android Layout Editor: How do I add a simple view?

Tags: android, user-interface, shapes, android-layout-editor

The Layout Editor's palette doesn't seem to have a blank view that I can drag in (unless my eyes are crazy).

Is there a way to drag a blank view from the palette in the Android Layout Editor onto the view I'm making (without having to type in the raw XML)?

Here's what I see under the "Common" section:
[image: Common Palette]

Here's what I see when I search for "view":
[image: Palette search for view]

Am I missing something?

I see a "< view >" under the "Containers" section, but that just pulls up a pop up with the same stuff that's already in the palette.

I'm new to Android dev and am coming from iOS where I can just drag a UIView right onto the storyboard. What's the equivalent of this behavior in Android?

Is there some way for me to add my own custom stuff to the Layout Editor palette?

Is typing `<View ... />` in the raw XML the only way of achieving this?

Comment: Use `View` ......

Comment: you're filtering for containers. View is not a container.

Comment: holy cow... it's under "Widgets"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My eyes are crazy.

Press "Widgets" (circled in red)

Drag in "View" (circled in green)

[image: found it]

Anyone able to explain why it's under "Widgets"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:alpha="0.5"` to set 50% opacity.

To use simple View, as an overlay for example, you can use the code below inside XML.

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/overlayOrSomethingElse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />
```

Comment: My question is not about setting opacity. My question has to do with dragging a blank view onto the Layout Editor. I'll rephrase my question better.

Comment: You can drag anything else and rename component to the `View`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `View` on the palette and you can do something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="243dp"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="349dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="469dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```